# RX + MOQ + TestScheduler

Tags: moq, system.reactive

Lets say I have:

- an object to be tested (it utilizes RX inside);
- number of test object dependencies, that utilize RX too - created using MOQ.

The question is:
is this an erroneous approach to use the same TestScheduler instance to control timings within the test object and for external observables?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For any specific test, you should (and must!) use the **same** TestScheduler for every object / method that requires / can take  an IScheduler, or else It Doesn't Work.™  ReactiveUI does this via having a global "MainThreadScheduler" object that can be overridden at test time, so you can do things like:

```
var oldSched = RxApp.MainThreadScheduler;
RxApp.MainThreadScheduler = new TestScheduler();

// Do a Test, and make sure all your test and runtime code use RxApp schedulers

RxApp.MainThreadScheduler = oldSched;
```

Or, the more elegant RxUI way is via .With()

```
(new TestScheduler()).With(sched => {
    // Do a test here.
});
```